# Passing an asynchronous function into onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I need to run an asynchronous function from onSnapshot, but onSnapshot is not an asynchronous function itself. How can I run an asynchronous function upon receiving notification that my collection has changed? Is there a way to work around this?

```
//Adds a listener to the user's offercandidate doc then sets the remote description to what appears in the document
let unsubscribeFromOffer = negDoc
  .collection("users")
  .doc(sessionStorage.getItem("userID"))
  .collection("offer-candidates")
  .onSnapshot(() => {
    postReturnAnswer();
  });

async function postReturnAnswer() {
  let doc = await negDoc
    .collection("users")
    .doc(sessionStorage.getItem("userID"))
    .collection("offer-candidates")
    .doc("offer")
    .get();

  let newPeerConnection = new UserConnection(
    servers,
    doc.data()["offer"]["senderID"]
  );

  newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
    doc.data()["offer"]["offer"]
  );

  let connAnswerDescription =
    await peerConnection.userPeerConnection.createAnswer();

  await peerConnection.userPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(
    connAnswerDescription
  );

  await negDoc
    .collection("users")
    .doc(sessionStorage.getItem("userID"))
    .collection("answer-candidates")
    .add({
      answer: JSON.stringify(
        peerConnection.userPeerConnection.localDescription
      ),
    });

  peerConnections.push(peerConnection);
}
```

Error message:

[image: Error]

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, but they center around the fact that doc.data() is not a function because doc is still in promise.

Comment: Why are you making the same query multiple times. You can pass the snapshot to your function instead

Comment: To answer your question, the easiest way to do that is to create an asynchronous function inside your onSnapshot function and call that function.

Comment: Hi @Jayson Meribe I've already tried and used async function into `onSnapshot` and used it successfully. Could you please include the error in your question.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Included the error

Comment: @SharpInnovativeTechnologies That's how I had it originally and received the same errors. I pass the function in for my own organizational purposes

Comment: @Phil I included the error

Comment: Which line does that refer to? Also, what browser are you using? I don't recognise that error and it's not clear what it means at all

Comment: @Phil I am using firefox and the error pertains to the first line in which doc.data() is used

Comment: You might want to check `doc.exists` before calling `doc.data()`

Comment: Hi @JaysonMeribe, I already posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code above, you're getting a single document on your async function. Looking at the [**Get a Document**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), it shows how to properly retrieve the contents of a single document using get():

I managed to get the error of undefined by using your code above. Using the code in the documentation would solve your error. You may want to look at the code below:

```
let unsubscribeFromOffer = negDoc
  .collection("users")
  .doc(sessionStorage.getItem("userID"))
  .collection("offer-candidates")
  .onSnapshot(() => {
    postReturnAnswer();
  });
    
async function postReturnAnswer() {
  let doc = await negDoc
    .collection("users")
    .doc(sessionStorage.getItem("userID"))
    .collection("offer-candidates")
    .doc("offer")
    .get()
    // This would map the data from the document
    .then((doc) => {
      // Check if the document exists.
      if (doc.exists) {   
        let newPeerConnection = new UserConnection(
          servers,
          // On this line, you already accessed on document level so you wont need to call the document again, just call the fieldname.
          doc.data().Fieldname
        );

        newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          // Same with this one.
          doc.data().Fieldname
        );

        let connAnswerDescription =
          await peerConnection.userPeerConnection.createAnswer();

        await peerConnection.userPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(
          connAnswerDescription
        );

        await negDoc
          .collection("users")
          .doc(sessionStorage.getItem("userID"))
          .collection("answer-candidates")
          .add({
            answer: JSON.stringify(
              peerConnection.userPeerConnection.localDescription
            ),
          });

        peerConnections.push(peerConnection);
      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```